# jquery change multidimensional array key in name attribute of form input element

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I want to change nth order array key in name attribute of input element

html markup is:

```
<tr><td><input name="rowkey" value="one"></td><td><input name="data[one][][name]"><input name="data[one][][date]"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="rowkey" value="one"></td><td><input name="data[one][][name]"><input name="data[one][][date]"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="rowkey" value="two"></td><td><input name="data[two][][name]"><input name="data[two][][date]"></td></tr>
```

The first key of all `<input name="data[]">` of second column of each row is the value of `<input name="rowkey">` of first column.

So that when i change the value of input name="rowkey" then all first keys of name="data[]" should change on that row.
for example i changed the value of input name="rowkey" of second row to "oonnee" then all first keys of name="data[]" on that row should change like this (pls notice changes in second row)

```
<tr><td><input name="rowkey" value="one"></td><td><input name="data[one][][name]"><input name="data[one][][date]"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="rowkey" value="oonnee"></td><td><input name="data[oonnee][][name]"><input name="data[oonnee][][date]"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="rowkey" value="two"></td><td><input name="data[two][][name]"><input name="data[two][][date]"></td></tr>
```

Its very simple to change the name attribute of any input field, but here i want to change the key of array which is in name attribute.

Please provide a solution where i can choose the order of array key to change because sometimes i need to change the third order key based on some input field.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you have any data in array such as `data[1]=name-of-element` and want to assign the name of that element to the `<input>` then you would need `templates` such as `JsViews` and `JsRenders` also `HandleBars` they will allow you to do so by compiling the markup at runtime